Issue rendering UI for websocket and golang API
My Project (Full code) https://github.com/poboisvert/poll-redis-pubsub
Based on https://medium.com/@ferdousazad12/real-time-voting-polling-system-with-go-websockets-redis-postgresql-and-docker-b414f122cb5b.
I am a bit stuck and need help in GO. Here is the situation:
This project has a client-side JavaScript file located at poll-redis-pubsub/client/main.js, which is responsible for handling user interactions with polls, including submitting votes. However, users may encounter a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error when trying to submit a vote. This issue arises because the client is likely hosted on a different origin (domain, protocol, or port) than the server, which is running at http://localhost:8080.
1 - CORS error. the server must be configured to allow requests from the client's origin. This can be done by setting the appropriate CORS headers in the server's response. In the poll-redis-pubsub/server/controllers/poll.go file, the CreatePoll, GetAllPolls, GetPollByID, and UpdatePoll functions already set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow all origins. Status: However, It doesn't seem to works or I can not find a better way to do it. URL http://localhost:8080/votes. If the server does not handle this endpoint correctly or does not include the necessary CORS headers, the request fail.
2 - WebSocket  I am trying to connect for real-time updates on votes. I am totally stuck at this part. If I could have a review or inputs...
To summarize

Service has CORS errors on POST for /votes.
WebSocket server is not running and accessible, and that it allows connections from the client's origin.

Fix CORS at root API and find a way to render websocket

Take a look in the browser debug console, my guess would be that your server is rejecting the preflight request (this is an OPTIONS request, your routers only handle POST/GET etc so will not be called). This question/answer may help. Note that you would be more likely to get a full answer if you include a minimal, reproducable example in the question itself.

I put the full repository since it has many files... and it's in go

Understood, and it's useful to have. However if you put in the effort to provide a minimal example in the question body its more likely you will get answers, some users will look at your links (I did) but a lot will not. In this case I suspect I've already given you the answer....

jup, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I fixed the project. It's working. Thank you guys
